# How to Create a Ballerina Integrator project in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, wso2-enterprise-integrator, ballerina, integrator, ballerina-vscode-plugin

I am learning Ballerina programming language and I have to do Integrations with Ballerina,I have installed and trying everything with VSCode only. But unable to create a Ballerina Integrator Project with VSCode, it shows message like Successfully created message only but project is not available in the specified folder. Please someone help me to do further.

Comment: What is the extension version that you are using?

Comment: vscode or ballerina which one u r asking

Comment: I was asking the vscode ballerina integrator extension version

Answer (score 2):

You can create a new project from VSCode Dashboard by entering CMD+SHIFT+P (on mac).

1. Click on Ballerina Integrator Dashboard
2. Click on Create a new Project
   [image: dashboard]
3. Enter the project name
   [image: project name]
4. The same as above enter a name for the module.
5. It will open a folder location where you need to save the project.
6. Click to create the project.
7. Then the project will open with a new window in VS Code.

Alternatively, you can create a new project from your project terminal and open it in the VSCode.

1. Go to the desired location in the terminal and type below to create the project.

> ballerina new [project-name]

eg: ballerina new project1

2. Navigate to the project directory and add a module using the following command.

> ballerina add [module-name]

ballerina add module1

3. You can open the project from the VSCode.

Please refer [3]

[3] - https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/ballerina-integrator/get-started/quick-start-guide/

Comment: Thank You. Actually i tried with alternative way only which u mentioned, i am able to do from that way. But from VSCode i am unable to create completely. Upto 6th step its going properly but it doesnt open the project in new terminal.

Comment: Please check whether you are using the latest Ballerina Integrator plugin (current 0.12.3) as well as the correct ballerina version (1.0.2 or 1.0.3).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using the latest Ballerina Integrator plugin (current 0.12.3) as well as the correct ballerina version (1.0.2 or 1.0.3).

Comment: Hi, I am using Ballerina Integrator 0.12.4 as well as Ballerina Version 1.0.3 only